# Hashes and different syntax: getting nils as return values when trying to access key-values

Tags: ruby

beginner programmer here who's been in it for a couple of months.

Assuming I have this block of code for a data structure:

```
users = {
admin: "secret",
admin2: "secret2",
admin3: "secret3"
}
```

When I try to access the value for a specific key like so: `users[:admin]`, I get a return value of `nil`, but if I use this syntax: `users['admin']`, I would get a return value of `"secret"`. Why does this happen? Aren't these two syntaxes supposed to be equivalent according to documentation.

Side question: when I create a `.yml` file for this data structure, and I try to set it up like this:

```
{
"admin" => "secret",
"admin2" => "secret2",
"admin3" => "secret3"
}
```

I would not be able to load ("parse") this file and get this error:

> did not find expected ',' or '}' while parsing a flow mapping at line 1 column 1

but the block of code in the beginning is perfectly fine. Again, I thought the syntax was supposed to be equivalent or perform the same function. Why does this happen? I think my weakest point in coding at this point are hashes because this confuses me so much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@Borsunho is correct in stating that `:admin` and `"admin"` are not equivalent. If you have come from a rails background with out understanding ruby this can be confusing since `params` Hash does not care. That is because `params` is a special class called `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

Implementing this is not too difficult but is besides the question.

As for your yml file it should be:

```
:admin: "secret"
:admin2: "secret2"
:admin3: "secret3"
```

This will parse out the same as your original `Hash`. The syntax is very different as yml is a way to store data structures and is independent of ruby or any of its syntax rules.

The leading colons mean this is a symbol, otherwise the keys will be parsed as strings.

e.g.

```
require 'yaml'
yml = <<YML
  :admin: "secret"
  :admin2: "secret2"
  :admin3: "secret3"
YML
YAML.load(yml)
#=> {:admin=>"secret", :admin2=>"secret2", :admin3=>"secret3"}

yml = <<YML
  admin: "secret"
  admin2: "secret2"
  admin3: "secret3"
YML 
YAML.load(yml)
#=> {"admin"=>"secret", "admin2"=>"secret2", "admin3"=>"secret3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:admin` is a `Symbol`. `'admin'` is a `String`. Hash will not treat them as the same key, even though they look similar.

Answer (score 0):

To start out with:

Your first code example

```
users = { admin: "secret" }
```

is not the same as

```
users = { "admin" => "secret" }
```

The first has symbols as keys. You know this because it's using the `key: val` syntax. Whenever keys are not symbols, they will use the "hash rocket" syntax in the second example. The second example here has strings as keys.

So you'd say `users[:admin]` for the first example and `users["admin"]` for the second.

Moving on to your question about yaml: your example code is not valid yaml. You can't just copy and paste ruby code into yaml; they have totally different syntaxes. You can run `puts YAML.dump(ruby_object)` to see what YAML for a hash would look like.